# how to remove a file with using execl function in UBUNTU

Tags: c, linux, shell

hi there i have to remove a file at end of a C programme but i couldnt make it. i tried to use

```
execl("/usr/bin/rm","rm","example.txt",NULL);
```

but it isnt working. i will be appreciate if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: The reason it does not work is because `rm` lives in `/bin/rm`, not in `/usr/bin/rm`. But as others have answered, it is not a good way to remove a file anyway.

Comment: You really should read a good book on Linux programming, like http://basepath.com/aup/ and http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ an you should read the output of `man 2 intro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not try `remove(const char *filename)` function in stdio.h?

Comment: actually i didnt know there is a function to remove a file in stdio.h and yeap it works properly thanks for your relpy.

Answer (score 4):

As other people pointed out, there are more efficient ways to remove a file.

If you want to know *why* your program is failing, just run it under `strace`:

```
strace your-binary
```

You'll see all the system calls that your program does, with the corresponding return values. In this case, I strongly suspect that `rm` is not in `/usr/bin`, but in `/bin`. You can check it by executing `which rm`.

Comment: thanks for your helpful post and yes i realized that it is in /bin